# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.Editext.getText()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-edittext, multiline

I am using EdiText Multiline and I got this error.

xText is my EditText multiline on activity

This is my code

String myText;
myText = xText.getText().toString(); // error here

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your xText object seems to be null.
How did you declare it? You should be using something like this:

```
xTest = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
```

Or maybe you are using view binding?

Comment: Hi. I don't think so. It's a EditText multiline. I have many others EditText that works fine. Just this there a problem. I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: If we read your error, it says that your edit text is null. Can you add more information about your code ? Because we need to know how xText is coming from